# Matplotlib boxplot: not showing whishi

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I could plot boxplot using [plt.bxp function](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bxp.html).

However, `whishi` value gets too high so the plot gets zoomed out. Is it possible to not show `whishi` value? I could not find any parameter for that in the documentation.

Here is an example of a boxplot where I cannot clearly see values other than `whishi`:

```
ys = [{'med': 1, 'q1': 0.5, 'q3': 1.5, 'whislo': 0, 'whishi': 100}, {'med': 2, 'q1': 1, 'q3': 3, 'whislo': 1, 'whishi': 200}]
fs = 10  # fontsize
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(6, 6), sharey=True)
axes.bxp(ys, showfliers=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe `axes.set_ylim(ymax=3.5)`?

Comment: This works perfectly but I have to set it up for each plot which is a bit tedious.

Comment: Well, you could calculate the value automatically, e.g. the maximum of the 'q3' values plus some margin. The exact calculation depends strongly on how your data is like.

Comment: `axes.set_ylim(ymax=max([y['q3']+eps for y in ys))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @Ed Smith and @JohanC mentioned in comments, I can solve this issue by setting a y-axis view limit based on the maximum of the third quartile `'q3'`'s values of all the boxplots and adding a small margin `eps` like so:

```
axes.set_ylim(ymax=max([y['q3']+eps for y in ys))
```

Comment: It says I will be allowed to do that only tomorrow. So I will accept it tomorrow.